# The different of Blank App & Blank Xaml App?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

May I ask about the different between the Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable) & Blank Xaml App(Xamarin.Forms Partable) 
because I found that some of the plugin cant't debug due to "Blank Xaml App(Xamarin.Forms Partable)" ?
As shown below image
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Functionally they should be identical.  One template just creates the default pages using XAML and code-behinds, and the other uses straight C# instead of XAML.